# Why is the value of process.memoryUsage().heapUsed always increasing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, settimeout

I have been trying to write a code where i can see heapused should  not be increased when setting timeout and removing the next time. But regardless the heapUsed is constantly increasing.

```
let process = require('process');

console.log('initial', process.memoryUsage().heapUsed);

let timeout;
function happen() {
  
  console.log('process', process.memoryUsage().heapUsed);
  
  clearTimeout(timeout);             // Clear previous timeout
  timeout = setTimeout(happen, 500); // Set next timeout
  
}
happen();
```

Comment: If you're in `Happen()` the timeout has already been invoked, there's no need to `clearTimeout(x)`

Comment: clearing timeout is to release the previously created setTimeout as setTimeout is always considered as global variable

Answer (score 1):

The `heapUsed` value is increasing due to the constant calling of the `happen` function, which creates an `Object` to store the result of `process.memoryUsage()`, and a `Timeout` to store the result of `setTimeout(...)`.

These values which get created *remain in the heap* for an indefinite amount of time (until the garbage collector removes them). [This article](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-node-js-garbage-collection/) has more information related to javascript garbage collection.